# how to rotate pages but not the text in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, rotation, itext, itext7

I'm trying to create a PDF document with some pages in portrait and others in landscape, but seeing this example ([iText7 - Page orientation and rotation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/clone-page-orientation-and-rotation)) I found that the page rotates to landscape but the text also does it ([PDF generated from iText7 samples](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/raw/master/src/test/resources/sandbox/events/cmp_page_rotation.pdf)), then, I need that the pages to rotate but the text continues from left to right, how in the next image.

Note: I tried to use `document.getPdfDocument().addNewPage(new PageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate()));`but it works for one page, not for the next x pages.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with setting page size

**For itextpdf 5.5.x**

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("D://qwqw12.pdf"));
doc.open();
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi"));
doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
doc.newPage();
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi2"));
doc.newPage();
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi3"));
doc.close();
```

this will create an A4-page with *Hi*, then an **landscape-oriented** page with *Hi2*, and last page will also be **landscape-oriented**. All new pages will be landscape-oriented until you don't set new page style via `setPageSize()`.

---

**For itextpdf 7.x**

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("D://qwqw12.pdf"));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi"));
doc.getPdfDocument().setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
doc.add(new AreaBreak());
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi2"));
doc.add(new AreaBreak());
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hi3"));
doc.close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But setPageSize method not works in iText7.

Comment: @Raul, sorry, totally missed you're using version 7 in your question. Update solution for 7th version.