# HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf i want to rotate mypage like PageSize.A4.Rotate()

Tags: c#, forms, nuget-package, itext7, pdfhtml

```
Windows Forms C# - Nuget-Package: Install-Package itext7.pdfhtml -Version 2.1.1
```

I am using this package for my project. How can I rotate or set page size. I am not using Document doc.

```
string RaporTemp = Dizinler.RaporTemp + "Temp_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".html";

string Output = Dizinler.PDFs + "Cari_Hareketleri_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".pdf";

File.WriteAllText(RaporTemp, text);
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileInfo(RaporTemp), new FileInfo(Output));

Process.Start(Output);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rotate pages but not the text in iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579992/how-to-rotate-pages-but-not-the-text-in-itext)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows: use the converter method which has either a `Document` or a `PdfDocument` as one of its arguments.

If you prefer the former, then create the `Document` instance using the needed page size.
If you prefer the latter, then set the default page size of the `PdfDocument` instance with `SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize)` method.

There should be no problem for you to move from one converter method to another, because the method which you use implicitly creates a `PdfDocument` instance and calls the method which requires it as an argument.